# Linux with Oracle's Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel on VMware?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, oracle, vmware-tools

I have a basic question and I want to make sure I have good understanding

I want to prepare a system to be used for Oracle Database (Development)

if I want to run (Oracle, CentOS, RedHat) Linux on Vmware with Oracle's Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel

then it should be in the following Order:

1- Install Linux
2- Install the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel
3- Install VMware-Tools

is that correct

I mean it is better than to Install Linux, VMware-Tools then Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel?

I want to fully understand the concept so I can write a tutorial to help other people (including me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the first one is the only correct way of doing that, as the vmware tools need to compile the kernel modules and these modules need to be compiled for the exact running kernel of your system (kernel version magic is a thing that you should understand).

Comment: Thanks allot, so it is 1- Install Linux 2- Install the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 3- Install VMware-Tools, cheers